# Playing a Video (MSDN Tutorial)

Tags: xna, msdn

When trying the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904198(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx the program crashes on

Line 69: "**player.Play(video);**"

error message: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll

Additional information: An unexpected error has occurred."

I did not change a single character in the code, but used exactly the files as they came out of the VideoPlayback_4_0.zip folder. (can be directly downloaded from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904198(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx)

I have read in other forums from people experiencing the same problem, but I could not find a usable solution. Does anybody know what causes the problem and how to fix it?

```
 Stack Trace    
 Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Helpers.ThrowExceptionFromErrorCode(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ErrorCodes error) + 0x3d bytes 
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.VideoPlayer.Play(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Video video) + 0xb7 bytes    
 VideoPlayback.exe!VideoPlayback.Game1.Update(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime) Line 69 + 0x1a bytes   
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick() + 0x4f0 bytes
```

Comment: i just downloaded and tried it and it works just fine, perhaps you are missing a codec or some .net security update or your OS ? All i did was download it, build and then run the x86 ver, it also runs from the project debug

Comment: thanks for trying, I'll check my codex and the .net libraries.

Comment: dont know if this will help you at all but I have cccp installed and all windows updates at their latest with VS 2010 installed and XNA4 only on XP SP3 32b and I have also tried it on my win 7 64b same thing all up to date.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the StackTrace property on the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codex were the problem. Reinstalling Windows resolved the issue.